# For each compact set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ its archetype $g^{-1}(A)$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous and bijective function. prove: For each compact set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ its archetype $g^{-1}(A)$ is compact.

I know from my course that...

4.6: Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous function and let $A \subset X$ compact. Thenn $f(A)$ is compact.

Can i use this in my proof? How can i start? Is this the right way?

---

Edit:
Some definitions from an older lesson i am allowed to use:

Let $I$ be an interval and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous and strictly monotonous increasing. Then the archetype $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Let I be an interval and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous and strictly monotonous increasing. We know from last lesson $f(I)=J$ is an interval. Then $f:I\rightarrow J$ is bijective and has the archetype $f^{-1}:J \rightarrow I$. The archetype is strictly monotonous increasing. Analog for strictly monotonous decreasing $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Such a bijective continuous $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonous and hence is a homeomorphism, i.e. $g^{-1}$ is also continuous. So then it follows from your quoted theorem.

Comment: great so my guess was right and i can use this as a reason but is it enough for a proof?

Comment: Do you know the first fact as a theorem? Otherwise you have to prove it. @hukachaka

Comment: unfortunately i have not found it anywhere in our script :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $g^{-1}(A)$ is compact proving that it is closed and bounded.

It is closed because $A$ is closed and $g$ is continuous.

In order to prove that $g^{-1}(A)$ is bounded, note that, since $g$ is continuous and injective, it must be increasing or decreasing. It can be assumed, without loss of generality, that it is increasing. Suppose that $g^{-1}(A)$ is not bounded above. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $g^{-1}(A)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$. Let $y\in\mathbb R$ such that $(\forall a\in A):a<y$. Since $g$ is surjective, $y=g(x)$, for some $x\in\mathbb R$. But, since  $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$, there is a natural $n$ such that $x_n>x$ and, since $g$ is increasing, $g(x_n)>g(x)=y$, which is impossible, since $x_n=a$.

The case in which $g^{-1}(A)$ is not bounded below is similar.